# Without data parameter with Firebase Functions for Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I tried this code at **Android**.

---

Initialize **Dependency**

```java
private FirebaseFunctions mFunctions;
```

In **onCreate()**

```java
mFunctions = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance();
```

Additional **Function**

```java
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("key1", "value1");
data.put("key2", "value2");

mFunctions.getHttpsCallable("HTTP_EVENT_NAME")
    .call(data)
    .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, String>() {
        @Override
        public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
            String result = (String) task.getResult().getData();
            return result;
        }
    });
```

It works fine!

But when I check the HTTP Request's **Body**, I can find this.

```
{ data: {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'} }
```

---

If I want to make it without `data` like this.

```
{ key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Callable functions in the client-side SDK are made to work with [Callable Cloud Functions on the server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#write_and_deploy_the_callable_function). The wire protocol is defined, and cannot be modified to fit other needs.

If you want full control over the format of the function parameters in the request body, you should implement a regular HTTP(S) Cloud Function. You'll also have to implement your own client-side client in that case.